# Best practice to store column-based data before to write to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I have the current code in Python 3:

```
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sp500_data = [
        {
            'company': 'GOOGLE',
            'headquarters': 'GOOGLEPLEX',
            'industry': 'ADS',
            'sector': 'TECH',
            'symbol': 'GOOG'
        },
        {
            'company': 'HEWLPA',
            'headquarters': 'WHATEVER',
            'industry': 'HARDWARE',
            'sector': 'TECH',
            'symbol': 'HP'
        }
    ]

    myfile = open("D:/test.csv", 'w', newline='')
    wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, fieldnames=sp500_data[0].keys)
    for sp500_company in sp500_data:
        wr.writerow(sp500_company)
```

However this gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\DEV\BlueTS\src\tsRetriever\dataRetriever\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    wr.writerow(sp500_company)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 146, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
  File "C:\Python33\lib\csv.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    wrong_fields = [k for k in rowdict if k not in self.fieldnames]
TypeError: argument of type 'builtin_function_or_method' is not iterable
```

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong, and in addition to this, I would like to know what is the best way in Python to store column-based data which was originally organised in tables.

Comment: Try to change this `sp500_data[0].keys` to this `sp500_data[0].keys()`. Not sure with Python 3, but with Python 2 `keys` is a method which returns a list, so you need to call it with `()`.

Comment: If you're dealing with tabular data, esp. financial data, check out [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org).  The `DataFrame` is a better storage object for multidimensional data than anything Python offers natively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to *call* the `.keys()` method:

```
wr = csv.DictWriter(myfile, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                    fieldnames=sp500_data[0].keys())
```

Note the `()` after `sp500_data[0].keys`; `.keys` is not an attribute, it is a method.

Using a `csv.DictWriter()` is an excellent method to turn data already in dictionary format into CSV data.

Comment: if you look at the file produced, it seems to give a strange result: the first row does not contain the header and the following rows contain the headers as well.

Comment: use [`wr.writeheader()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader) to write a header to the file. The sample code you gave, once fixed, won't write keys, just values.

Comment: Effectively it removed they keys, however instead of having `MMM` it prints `b'MMM'`, do you happen to know why ?

Comment: That is byte data, not unicode text. Decode bytes values to unicode first.

Comment: I am lost here, do you happen to have a link ?

Comment: You can use a dict comprehension:  `{key: value.decode('utf8') for key, value in row.items()}`, where `row` is the dictionary to decode.